# How can I achieve in Filemaker results similar to GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: sql, filemaker, group-concat

I am doing some work in a program called Filemaker which has a watered down sql function.  It does not have the `GROUP_CONCAT` function and the `GROUP BY` clause requires all fields mentioned in the `SELECT`.

Is there another away to get the same results of:

```
SELECT id_candidate, GROUP_CONCAT(id_award SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM nomination 
GROUP BY id_candidate
```

result

```
5   113, 116
6   109, 113, 114, 117, 120
7   104, 113
8   113
9   101, 104, 113, 118
10  100, 114, 118
```

Note: if it needs to done over multiple selects I can store the results of one `SELECT` and use it in another. So I could use the results of `SELECT DISTINCT (id_candidate)` and then call it in a `…WHERE IN ({var})`

Comment: Is your question about SQL or about FileMaker? If the latter, please explain what tables and fields you have, and what is the intended use of the result (e.g. do you need this as an exported text file). In general, FileMaker has its own, non-SQL, methods to organize data. You should reserve the use of SQL to those rare cases where the native methods are unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question - you can't do it in FileMaker SQL in a single statement - it has very limited support for subqueries.

> I could use the results of SELECT DISTINCT (id_candidate) and then
>   call it in a …WHERE IN ({var})

I would suggest doing the opposite. Store calculated query in FileMaker at the record level e.g. a calculated field called "awards":

```
ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT id_award 
              FROM nomination 
              WHERE id_candidate = ?" ; 
"" ; ", " ; nomination::id_candidate )
```

Then you can run your report:

```
   ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT id_candidate, awards
                 FROM nomination 
                 GROUP BY id_candidate" ; 
    "" ; "" )
```

This should allow you to have the desired output

Comment: While I was trying to avoid creating a field in the candidate table I believe this might be the only current solution for now.

Comment: I think, it is the easiest approach. If you do not have access to the fields definitions, I would suggest looping through the records and building the reports with a script.